# Save JSON data onto the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

To begin have a look at the following fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ob43hwdu/1/

with help from this community, JSON data are displayed on screen upon the user hitting the generate button. In the sense that they are various input field that user fills in and when they hit generate, it populates the json data on screen.

What I would want to do is have another input and button known as name and confirm, and once the user clicks on it, it produces a json file with those information that is stored at lets say http://..json/NAMEPROVIDED.json

In other words, as far as button goes, I could have:

```
<fieldset id="buildyourform">
    <legend>test</legend>
</fieldset>
<input type="button" value="Add a field" class="add" id="add" />
<input type="button" value="Generate" class="add" id="preview" />&nbsp;
<pre id="json"></pre>
<input type="text" value="name of file">
<input type="button" value="submit">
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need server side scripting here. Post the JSON to a PHP/ASPX script and echo it with a correct header back to the user.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is of the __you need a web server__ variety.

Answer (score 2):

You wont be able to this with just javascript, jquery, html, json or html5.
You'll need some serverside processing to get the string and save it on the system.
PHP is simple to use but you have to check what's instaled on your server and if you have permission to create/save files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) or [OpenWS](http://openws-app.herokuapp.com/) that will allow you to hook your form submission into something that can save JSON objects into a backend.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I've looked into OpenWS it seems interesting. Could you kindly elaborate on how I could incorporate this code with it?

Comment: With your JS have it so that when the submit button is clicked, it pushes your "item" JSON object using their API (the example code is on their page under "Save your first JSON object"). 

Just swap out where they have "taskJSON" with your JSON (item), and instead of "my_tasks" in the URL you can make it "my_item". Then you can always reference the saved JSON as "ttps://openws.herokuapp.com/my_item" (with your key).

Comment: thank you, but how about if I want to store that in my own server rather than a third party server?